# Performance using cache or anyway

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using memory cache for some data that use very much in second with most of the users for good performance in my app, but I want to know is there any way to use instead of cache? I am using .net core 2.2 and sql server 2016

Comment: you can use optimize memory table in sql server and config it in entity framework, this link can be useful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Furthermore, you an use natively compiled stored procedure with a optimized memory table.

Comment: @hassan.ef thanks about your answer, I am new in entityframework can you show example to me about Memory-Optimized Tables in entityframework?

Comment: @– Arnaud Peralta thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the table an entity is mapped to is memory-optimized. When using EF Core to create and maintain a database based on your model (either with migrations or Database.EnsureCreated()), a memory-optimized table will be created for these entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .ForSqlServerIsMemoryOptimized();
}
```